# What's the correct way to check that an asset file exists?

Tags: plugin-development, assets, php

If I have an asset resource, loaded successfully from the database, whose corresponding file no longer exists on its Volume (irrespective of Volume type), what is the best way to find out if the file exists, in PHP?

`file_exists` or maybe `is_file`?

Or is there an inbuilt method in Craft I should be using?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP's `file_exists` function is perfectly fine for checking this.

```php
$exists = file_exists($path);
```